# WCF --> WebClient --> Browser results in broken JSON

Tags: jquery, json, wcf

I have a WCF service that returns about 10MB of JSON. This is then consumed by an ASPX page which acts as a proxy to get around cross site request issues. The ASPX page does this:

```
 Response.Write(webClient.DownloadString(url));
```

The response is then downloaded using jQuery's ajax() method in the user's browser (reproduced in Chrome and Firefox.) This is all over a local network so speed isn't an issue. The problem that I'm having is that every now and then the JSON that I get back is corrupt. It has things like this in it:

```
..."DeletePermission":true,"HasChildren":f:true,"HasChildren":false...
```

It happens so infrequently (and only on production servers) that it is very hard to debug. Does anyone have any idea at what point this could be breaking? I'm leaning towards it being an issue with the browser because if the data was corrupted in transit then the packet would be dropped. Has anyone experienced anything like this before?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: are you setting InstanceContextMode?